# Decompressing a tar.gz makes its owner 1000 1000

Tags: debian

I'm logged in via PuTTY as root and am trying to decompress `/root/multicraft-1.8.2-64.tar.gz`.

I do this using the `tar zxf /root/multicraft-1.8.2-64.tar.gz` command. However, two odd things happen:

- It originally took the owner/group of `openvpn`
- When I did the `userdel openvpn` command, it now makes the owner `1000 1000`.

When I try to run the `setup.sh` file, it says `Error: Can't find 'bin/'! This script needs to be started from inside the Multicraft package directory.`, however that file exists.

Comment: tar --no-same-owner

Answer (score 1):

**Problem #1 tar**
What's your problem with this? This is quite normal behaviour, just chown the files

```
chown -R <youruser>:<yourgroup> <folder>
```

e.g.

```
chown -R multicraft:multicraft multicraft-1.8.2
```

Side note: I'd further suggest to add a new system user for security reasons (man *useradd* will help). Then chown the files to that user and have it run the multicraft binary. Do yourself a favour and do not run the binary as root in production.

**Problem #2**
You might have to cd into the multicraft directory first.

```
cd multicraft-1.x.x.x
./setup.sh
```